# Python CGI with API

Tags: python, cgi, webapi

I am quite new to Python, I have built some applications in Python with CGI and I found cgi is much easier compare to a framework as I have full control on everything.
Tried to build a web API through below module but it end up with a web page rather than an API.

```
import cgi
import cgitb
```

I would like to create a web API, as I am familiar with cgi I would like to create it (web API) through python cgi,I have been looking for a good documentation but I didn't find any. It would be helpful if someone can give me a clue. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: What is your question? And you really shouldn't build anything more than a simple toy page with CGI.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question is off-topic as per the site guidelines. Please check [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGI applications are nothing but backend of HTTP kind protocol, so I guess you could naturally build REST API on top of it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Also python have good build-in support for HTTP for better understanding from inside (in case u like to keep control on everything): https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#module-http.server

Anyway, when your getting better in it your best bet to switch on a framework like these: https://www.djangoproject.com/ http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/

Comment: I realise that you're new here, but please don't use txtspeak like "ur" in your answers (and questions) on Stack Exchange sites. When you fix your answer, I'll delete this comment. (PS: Nice work getting such a high score on your first day!).

Comment: It's great that you're enthusiastic to answer questions on SO, but your answers will be even more valuable if you follow the advice in [Help Center > Answering](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), eg "We don't expect every answer to be perfect, but answers with correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar are easier to read. They also tend to get upvoted more frequently. Remember, you can always go back at any time and edit your answer to improve it". Actually, it's very worthwhile reading all of the Help pages...

Comment: Thanks @Mux for your quick answer,I will have a look at REST in Python and see if i can intergrate cgi with it.

Comment: Thanks @Mux for your quick answer,I will have a look at REST in Python and see if i can intergrate cgi with it.